# Create hash table from the contents of a file

Tags: python

How can I open a text file, read the contents of the file and create a hash table from this content? So far I have tried:

```
import json

json_data = open(/home/azoi/Downloads/yes/1.txt).read()

data = json.loads(json_data)
pprint(data)
```

Comment: As you are new to Python, I recommend reading a book about it at first or complete [Google Python Class](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/edu/languages/google-python-class/). It won't take a lot of time, as Python is very simple, especially if you're familiar with other programming languages. It also has great documentation for standard functions available at http://docs.python.org/

Comment: Is the file json data? Please describe the file's formatting a little bit. Also, what was your error? Why doesn't the code you tried work? (Aside from the non-string input to the `open(...)` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest this solution:

```
import json

with open("/home/azoi/Downloads/yes/1.txt") as f:
    data=json.load(f)
    pprint(data)
```

The `with` statement ensures that your file is automatically closed whatever happens and that your program throws the correct exception if the open fails. The `json.load` function directoly loads data from an open file handle.

Additionally, I strongly suggest reading and understanding the [Python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html) tutorial. It's essential reading and won't take too long.

Answer (score 0):

To open a file you have to use the open statment correctly, something like:

```
json_data=open('/home/azoi/Downloads/yes/1.txt','r')
```

where the first string is the path to the file and the second is the mode: `r = read, w = write, a = append`